# devcontainers without VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Let's say that for some reason I don't want to launch VSC to get a devcontainer shell running, but I still want all of that devcontainer goodness without rewriting all of the configuration files. There's a `devcontainer` CLI, but at the moment, the only options available are `open` (VSC, connected to the container) and `build` (which builds the image, in the use case that many people are sharing the same devcontainer environment).

Ideally, there'd be a third option `devcontainer shell` which does all the build, spin up and connection work that is done inside VSC, but the just `exec`s to the running container.

Answer (score 1):

The `.devcontainer` folder contains a `devcontainer.json` file. In it, if you're using docker-compose, there will be a `dockerComposeFile` key with an array of docker-compose files, loaded in order. You can do the same with a command such as `docker-compose -f first-compose-file.yml -f second-compose-file.yml`.

That same folder usually has its own `docker-compose.yml` file. You will notice it declares your main service and usually sets up a volume to share between the host and the container (useful to work inside the container).

There are other interesting keys in `devcontainer.json` such as `forwardPorts`, `remoteUser` or `postCreateCommand`. You should be able to set up most of them in your docker-compose file (dev stuff should go into the `.devcontainer/` one). The post-create command can be run with `docker compose exec SERVICENAME COMMAND`.

I don't know if there's a command to detect `.devcontainer` files and pick up the right settings, but it should not be hard to write one.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [@devcontainers/cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@devcontainers/cli) ?
I see [here](https://containers.dev/) that it is actively developed by microsoft

I am trying it at the moment. Unfortunately, I fell on many errors like *"An error occurred setting up the container"*, so do not expect a polished DX